# Low flow rate from new Delta valve

Tags: bathtub, delta

Newly remodeled bathroom. I had the plumber install a Delta R10000-UNWS (with stops) valve for the tub/shower. When tiled, he installed a Delta Monitor 17 series trim (spout, handle, shower head). According to the specs from Delta, I should be getting 6gpm at 60psi from the tub spout (PRV is set to 60psi). I measured the flow from the tub spout twice (with no other water on in the house) and I’m only getting 2gpm.

The plumber says it’s a valve or cartridge limitation but per Delta that’s false.

What could be wrong?

Comment: I believe there are something called screwdriver stops which should be unscrewed (all the way?) to get maximum flow rate.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered if those stops were possibly the problem. I’ll give that a try and see if it helps. The plumber may have screwed them in and forgot.

Comment: The stop screws were indeed not all the way out. That helped with the flow rate. I went from about 2gpm to now 3gpm. Much better, but still about half what the specs say I should be getting. What else can I troubleshoot? Is it worth taking the spout itself off to see if there's some kind of blockage? Is it worth checking the cartridge?

Comment: How much pressure are you getting before the PRV? Where is the PRV physically? If it is in your basement and your shower it two stories up then you cannot expect 60 PSI.  Subtract 0.433 PSI for every foot of elevation according to https://www.irrigationtutorials.com/elevation-pressure-loss-in-irrigation-systems/

Comment: Please direct me to the documentation which states "6gpm at 60psi" for your Delta R10000-UNWS

Comment: I am over 150 psi before the PRV. You wouldn’t believe the pressure. It’s high across the whole city and higher in some zones than others. The pressure has always been solid in my city but they increased it a few years back. There were several areas that had mains blow or pipes burst (in the street).

Comment: https://www.deltafaucet.com/sites/delta/files/2019-11/Delta%20Flow%20Chart%202018-06-27.pdf

According to the link just above (17 series cartridge with the UNWS valve), the flow rate from the tub spout should be 5.7gpm. Based on the derating info you provided I should have 53.5 PSI conservatively (it’s under a 15 ft rise). To be clear, I’m rubbing the test with the temperature handle right in the middle where I’m getting max flow rate.

Comment: Did you also account for all your elbows and other joints? https://media.wattswater.com/Orion-HP-FrictionLoss.pdf

Comment: I haven’t but even if that took me to 40 psi, I should still be getting 1.6gpm higher than I’m getting now. I am going to adjust the PRV closer to 80 psi and see how much that helps.